# How to make python script run faster?

Tags: python, bots, screenshot, pyautogui

I have a python script that takes screenshots of some parts of the screen and if the arranged RGB code matches, clicks on the object. It works well on not moving objects. However, when the object moves, it can not click on it due to delay. I do not know the direction of the object, it is random. Therefore, I can not solve the problem by rearranging the click coordinates.

Do you have any advice? Is there a better way to write this script? Is there any trick to click faster the found coordinates or find the desired coordinates more quickly? Object recognization does not work well due to background.

Thank you!

```
import pyautogui
import keyboard
import time
import win32api, win32con

time.sleep(2)

def click(x,y):
    win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y))
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,0,0)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,0,0)



while 1:
    pic = pyautogui.screenshot(region=(265,220,200,200))
    width, height = pic.size

    for x in range(0,width,10):
        for y in range(0,height,10):
            r, g, b = pic.getpixel((x,y))

            if g in range(90,95):
                click(x+265,y+220)
                time.sleep(1)
                break
```

Comment: SO is more focused on fixing code. For questions on improving working code, try [CodeReview.SE].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some suggestions to try:

```
roi = (265,220,200,200)
width, height = roi[2]-roi[0], roi[3]-roi[1]
range_x = range(0,width,10)
range_y = range(0,height,10)



while 1:
    pic = pyautogui.screenshot(region=roi)
    
    img_g = np.array(pic)[:,:,1] # get the green channel
    g_in_range = (95<img_g)&(90<img_g) 
    for x in range_x :
        for y in range_y :
            g = img_g((y,x)) # double check x,y order

            if g:
                click(x+265,y+220)
                time.sleep(1)
                break
```

If you need even more speedup:

Try following [this article](https://pyimagesearch.com/2017/08/28/fast-optimized-for-pixel-loops-with-opencv-and-python/) about using `cython`.

Answer (score 2):

Try OpenCV for object detection, with (SIFT) or (SURF).
Something like this

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pyautogui
import time
import win32api, win32con

# Load the reference image of the object you want to detect
ref_img = cv2.imread('object_reference.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# Initialize the SIFT detector
sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()

# Detect keypoints and descriptors in the reference image
kp1, des1 = sift.detectAndCompute(ref_img, None)

# Set up the mouse click function
def click(x,y):
    win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y))
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,0,0)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,0,0)

# Set the region of interest where you want to search for the object
roi = (265, 220, 200, 200)

# Set the threshold for matching the object
threshold = 0.7

# Set the delay between clicks
delay = 1

# Wait for 2 seconds to let the user move the object into the region of interest
time.sleep(2)

# Continuously search for the object in the region of interest
while True:
    # Take a screenshot of the region of interest
    img = pyautogui.screenshot(region=roi)

    # Convert the screenshot to grayscale
    img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(np.array(img), cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

    # Detect keypoints and descriptors in the screenshot
    kp2, des2 = sift.detectAndCompute(img_gray, None)

    # Match the descriptors between the reference image and the screenshot
    bf = cv2.BFMatcher()
    matches = bf.knnMatch(des1, des2, k=2)

    # Apply ratio test to filter out false matches
    good_matches = []
    for m, n in matches:
        if m.distance < threshold * n.distance:
            good_matches.append(m)

    # If enough good matches are found, assume the object is detected and click on it
    if len(good_matches) > 10:
        # Get the center of the detected object by averaging the keypoints
        obj_center = np.mean(np.array([kp2[m.trainIdx].pt for m in good_matches]), axis=0)

        # Click on the center of the detected object
        click(int(obj_center[0]) + roi[0], int(obj_center[1]) + roi[1])

        # Wait for a short delay before searching for the object again
        time.sleep(delay)
```